# "In cases where" vs. "in the event"

Tags: word-choice, legalese

> - In cases where either party is unable to perform the contracted obligation...
> - In the event either party is unable to perform the contracted obligation...

Which phrase is preferable and why? I prefer the second but having used "in the event" several times, I would like to add some variety.

Comment: This depends. Are there many possible scenarios in which you can or would expect such a problem to arise ("In cases where...), or is it such that once the obligation is abrogated, the whole thing stops (in the event that...)?

Comment: Thank you @Questor. I wonder what the reason is for the down vote. I suppose it is not coming from you.

Answer (score 1):

**In the event that either party cannot fulfill their contractual obligation(s).**

I believe that this flows better, and follows the typical language I've seen used in other documents.

Answer (score 1):

Defective performance of the stated obligations arising from any party subject to these contract terms shall result in...

(Black's Law Dictionary and an excellent 2nd grade teacher)